# How to create my own header file in TI ccs6.0

Tags: c

I start to learn TI's  msp430  MCU.
 I created my own header file, and specify the search path for the C preprocessor
 (Project → Properties → Build → MSP430 Compiler→ Include Options, add my own header file path), when i buiLd my project, the ccs remind error:unresolved symbol Blink_LED(I have define the function in  my  own header file )

Comment: Please add your code to the question

Comment: Adding the search path to your IDE does not automatically means the include(s) in that path are always added to each project. You still need `#include "whatever.h"` in your source.

Comment: i have added  #include “Blink.h” to my project

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add it using:

Rigth mouse click on Project > New > Header File

No need to add it to the preprocessor path.

Futhermore an unresolved symbol is mostly because the linker cannot find the library defining the symbol. So if you need to add somethink, add it to the linker "File Search Path"

Comment: something wrong , if add header file like the way ,it does not  need and #include<xxxx.h> ,it works correctly.   i want to add external  header file  in external directory  that i have already defined my own header file.

Comment: Then you should add it to the Project > Properties > Build > ARM Compiler > Include Options
Don't forget to also add the corresponding library to the linker file search path.

Comment: when i copy my directory that contain header file to ccs6.0 Project ,it works  correctly.   If specify the search path for the my own header  file directory ,project must contain the directory .